# impossible constraint in 'asm'

Tags: c, assembly

I'm using third party library which compiled one week ago.
Today I sat down at the desk again, i pushed build again, then my head blown out.
I've been shot with this error:

> impossible constraint in 'asm'

The code is:

```
static inline unsigned ROLc(unsigned word, const int i)
{
   asm ("roll %2,%0"
      :"=r" (word)
      :"0" (word),"I" (i));
   return word;
}
```

Some mystery things happens...only thing which I'm thinking right now is *'WTF?'*
Platform Intel CoreDuo with W32 XP on board.

Two additional questions:

1. what could destroy my build?
2. I suppose that asm syntax is incorrect, so how can i fix that?
3. Where can I find 'cool' asm reference (I mean some cpp reference like over pure processor commands list datasheet/manual)

regards
P.

**UPDATE:**
Haha I feel like dump-ass, last week i've installed strawberry perl...which installs and throws gcc on path and my build system takes 'default' compiler....:D
However i've fixed that using :

```
return (word << i) | (word >> (32 - i));
```

Comment: But surely, a `var << shift` would be compiled as a `rol` instruction?

Comment: It's the code from library, not mine.  Maybe '<< | >>' would be compiled to 'roll | rorl',but I'm not into asm so much...however still have no idea why it's compiling no more...

Comment: @Skizz No, the rotation instructions can only be implemented in pure C with two shifts and an or. The C expression `var << shift` would be compiled with a `sal` instruction.

Comment: Oops. You're right. It's rol not shl. Doh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You might have auto-upgraded to a new compiler, that has changed the syntax
2. [This](http://www.mail-archive.com/linux-kernel@vger.kernel.org/msg79192.html) suggests using Ic rather than I; I didn't test this
3. Not sure what you mean, a C++ reference for assembly doesn't make a lot of sense to me. [This](http://www.mail-archive.com/linux-kernel@vger.kernel.org/msg79192.html) is an (old) HOWTO on gcc and inline assembly, it might be what you're after?

Comment: ad.3 I prefer c++ reference site, or sphinx like 'look&feel', thats only thing which i was looking for. BTW. your 'old howto' link is the same as link from point 2.